# Can open settings in Linux Mint only using the terminal and when logged in as the root user

Tags: linux-mint, display-settings

I've been using Linux Mint for a week and today I noticed that I'm unable to open the system settings and the startup applications app.

I have rebooted the pc, clicked many times on these apps to open but they didn't.

I've also tried to open the settings from the terminal using the commands:

```
cinnamon-settings
cinnamon-settings panel
```

this also didn't work and the terminal threw an error saying :

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

### UPDATE :

Now, I remarked that I can't use other apps like the online accounts app and the Cinnamon effects apps.

I just noticed that I can run the system settings from terminal using the previous commands but only if I'm logged in as the root user.

So what should I do to be able to open system installed apps even when I'm not logged in as the root user ?

### UPDATE 2 :

After some research in the internet, I found that the issue is related to changing some language settings, but I still don't know how to fix it.
(btw I have really changed some language settings because I couldn't set the default keyboard layout to AZERTY)

Comment: Have you tried updating the system?

Comment: @0x1a4 I don't have any update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, searching on the web I found this
[post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188353) that solved to me.
I had to install Pillow again and everything back to normal.

```bsh
 pip install Pillow==2.7.0
```

hope it helps you to.

Comment: I can't believe it, it workeeeed ! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Using strace, I saw cinnamon-settings failing to load libfribidi.

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Pillow-8.3.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libfribidi.so

I solved the problem by installing the FriBidi development package (libfribidi-dev) and building Pillow 8.3.1 from source. This includes Fribidi in Pillow. I then moved the existing Pillow out of the way and installed the one I built.

Trying to copy (symbolic link) the system's libfribisi.so where Pillow expects it did not work.